# Select lowest value in a column from a set

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have a table in PostgreSQL that has information like this:

```
ID | Value | Total
12 | 'foo' | 16
15 | 'loo' | 1
13 | 'too' | 11
67 | 'roo' | 7
```

The query I have to build will be given either a single ID or multiple IDS which are comma separated. Only the Value needs be returned. If there are multiple IDs then return only the result of the set that has the lowest Total.

This is my start, but it isn't exactly what I am after:

```
IF(position(',' in sample_id)>0) THEN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT value FROM table WHERE table.id = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(sample_id,','));
ELSE
    RETURN QUERY SELECT value FROM table WHERE table.id = sample_id;
END IF;
```

**EDIT:** To be clear I am building a function that

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_test_results(IN sample_id text)
    RETURNS TABLE(test_result text) AS
    $BODY$
    BEGIN
        IF(position(',' in sample_id)>0) THEN
            RETURN QUERY SELECT value FROM table WHERE table.id = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(sample_id,','));
        ELSE
            RETURN QUERY SELECT value FROM table WHERE table.id = sample_id;
        END IF;
    END;
    $BODY$
```

It is used:

```
get_test_results("342949283940829308")
```

OR

```
get_test_results("67, 12")
```

The ID values in this call do not correlate to the example table. The result should ONLY return the value from the lowest TOTAL of the IDs in the set if there is more than one ID passed to the function.

Comment: provide example of given input and desired out put

Comment: `table.id = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(sample_id,','));` will work just fine for a single value as well. No need for an `if` statement. But it's totally unclear what you mean with "*the result of the set that has the lowest total*". Please [edit] your question and add the expected output based on a sample input

Comment: Updated to add input and output

Comment: @a-horse-with-no-name The naming is terrible. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a limit clause:

```
select value 
from the_table
where id = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(sample_id,',')::int[])
order by total 
limit 1;
```

Note that you also need to cast the result of `regexp_split_to_array` to an integer array (`::int[]`) otherwise you cannot use `any()` to compare that with an integer column.

You also don't need PL/pgSQL for this. A simple SQL function will do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.get_test_results(IN sample_id text)
   RETURNS TABLE(test_result text) AS
$BODY$
  select value 
  from the_table
  where id = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(sample_id,',')::int[])
  order by total 
  limit 1;
$BODY$
language sql;
```

Note that if there are multiple rows with the same minimum value, the above will only return a single row.

If you need all those rows, you can use a window function:

```
select value
from (
  select value, dense_rank() over (order by total) as rnk
  from the_table
  where id = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(sample_id,',')::int[])
) t
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `min(table.total)` in a nested select.

I don't use PostgreSQL but if your example is valid, you should write:

```
RETURN QUERY SELECT table.value FROM table WHERE table.id = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(sample_id,',')) and table.total in (
    SELECT min(tbl.total) FROM table tbl WHERE tbl.id = ANY(regexp_split_to_array(sample_id,','))
);
```

Note that as stated in a comment, you don't need to check if you pass a single or multiple values since splitting your argument works in both cases.